# Hold download in wget till my connection is established

Tags: wget

I want to download a file [Ttytter](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dist2/2.0.02.txt) using wget and run it in the terminal. I can do that by `gnome-terminal --tab -e 'wget http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dist2/2.0.02.txt -O /tmp/ttytter.pl && perl /tmp/ttytter.pl -hold'` but if my connection is not established then how do I make wget to wait till connection established and then download the file.

Comment: Have you tried the new suggestions in my answer? It should be what you want!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do would be to write a script which pinged the url until it was available and then launched your command when the link came up. The script could use a while loop for the ping command, and when the url was available, the loop could be broken and your command would be run. There are some good scripts [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/42021/how-to-ping-in-linux-until-host-is-known), which could be adapted and which explain the process in detail.

Good news, I have just tested the script below by going off-line and then coming back on again and it gives me a copy of `ttytter.pl` in my tmp folder and launches the program!

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do ping -c1 www.floodgap.com > /dev/null && break; done
wget http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dist2/2.0.02.txt -O /tmp/ttytter.pl && perl /tmp/ttytter.pl -hold done
```

Once you have saved this script and made it executable, you can simply add it as a startup item using the graphical startup manager (but remember to check the option to **run as an application in the terminal**). Alternatively, put this command in the appropriate area of the box provided by the startup manager: `gnome-terminal -e /location/of/above/script`

If you have any problems with placing the script in startup, you can create a `launcher` for it, select to run it as an **application in the terminal**, then pin it to your panel or desktop. Then click the launcher after you login and it will wait until the connection is established and will then download and launch `ttytter`.

Comment: I tried `wget --tries=50 http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dist2/2.0.02.txt -O /tmp/ttytter.pl`
with error 

    --2012-07-25 01:26:29--  http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dist2/2.0.02.txt
    Resolving www.floodgap.com (www.floodgap.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
    wget: unable to resolve host address `www.floodgap.com'

Comment: Yes you're right; I got the same error. I think writing a script probably would be the best thing as it might not be possible to do what you want with wget.

Comment: can you guide me? and also it should start up at boot.

Comment: yes-take a look at my edited answer; it now contains a script and some instructions.

Comment: I copied ttytter to /usr/bin making it executable. pinned a starter to startup-applications.